# testing fastapi response to next.js with fetch, promise stuck in pending?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch, atomicassets

my fetch is stuck in pending when I query a fastapi endpoint in local dev.

followed this blog and a few others - https://damaris-goebel.medium.com/promise-pending-60482132574d

Using this fetch code (having simplified it drastically just to get a simple solution working)

```
function fastapiRequest(path) {
    return fetch(`${path}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response;
      }
      );
```

into a constant variable i.e.,

```
const xxxx = fastapiRequest(
    `http://0.0.0.0:8008/xcascasc/Dexaa/Emo.json?Magic=Dexxaa&emotion=expressions`
  );
```

Ideally I want to use UseSWR to do this as I'm using next.js, but first of all, just need it to work :)

A postman query like this works fine to return a value

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://0.0.0.0:8008/xcaxc/dexxa/emo.json?analysis=statistical&substance=dexxa&emo=powa' \
--header 'x_token: 13wdxaxacxasdc1'
```

the value is left like this in console.log

```
data show here? Promise {<pending>}
```

With the initial response being

```
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'url', redirected: false, status: 200, ok: true, …}
```

#### Update based on answers.

Using each of the proposed answers, I am still not getting the data returned appropriately. i.e.,

```
function fastApiRequest(path) {
    console.log("really begins here");
    return fetch(`${path}`, { mode: 'cors' })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response', response);
        return response.json();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        throw err;
      });
  }

async function test() {
    console.log('begins');

    return await fastApiRequest(
      `http://0.0.0.0:8008/xxxx/dex/adea.json?deaed=adedea&adee=deaed&adeada=adeeda`
    );
  }

  const ansa = test();
```

Is giving a response of pending at the moment.

The backend is built with fastapi, with these CORS, I'm wondering if I need to give it more time to get the data? (postman works fine :/)

```
def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

origins = [
    "http://moodmap.app",
    "http://localhost:3000/dashboard/MoodMap",
    "http://localhost:3000",
    "http://localhost",
    "http://localhost:8080",
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
        max_age=3600,

)
```

I am running the fastapi code in a docker container as well btw

Comment: `xxxx` is a promise. So you have either to `await` it or attach a `then().catch()` chain (as also explained in the linked article)

Comment: Even with all the changes you did, you're still not awaiting the `test()` call. It should be `const ansa = await test();` since `test` also returns a promise. It's the same issue you were having before, and the same exact solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

> The Response object, in turn, does not directly contain the actual JSON response body but is instead a representation of the entire HTTP response. So, to extract the JSON body content from the Response object, we use the json() method, which returns a second promise that resolves with the result of parsing the response body text as JSON.

`.json()` is an async method (it returns a Promise itself), so you have to assign the parsed value in the next `.then()`. So your code can be changed like this.

```js
function fastApiRequest(path) {
    let res;
    fetch(`${path}`)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => (res = data))
    .then(() => console.log(res));
    
    return res;
}

response =  fastApiRequest('https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts?limit=10');
console.log('response')
```

If you want to use `async/await` approach, below is the code.

```js
async function fastApiRequest(path) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(path);
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

async function test() {
  console.log(await fastApiRequest('https://proton.api.atomicassets.io/atomicassets/v1/accounts?limit=10'))
}
test()
```

Answer (score 2):

first you need to parse the response into json if it's a json API.

```js
function fastapiRequest(path) {
    return fetch(`${path}`)
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
       });
}
```

you need to 'await' for the rsponse

> you need to write the below code in an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

```js
const xxxx = await fastapiRequest(
    `http://0.0.0.0:8008/xcascasc/Dexaa/Emo.json?Magic=Dexxaa&emotion=expressions`
  );
```

When you make an http request using fetch in javascript it will return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), it's not stuck it's just need to be resloved, you can resolve it just like the above code with async await, or you can use the `.then(() => { /* code... */ })` function, you can also use `.catch(() => { /* handle error... */ })` function to handle errors.

Answer (score 0):

In Your `curl` you use `x_token` as header variable, if it's required you need to pass a header with your path too. All other answers are valid too.